# How to start going to gym the right way?

Tags: gym

I'm doing some home exercises for quite some time, but I also want to start going to the gym, the problem is I don't know how to do the exercises there, nor I know how any of the fitness instruments and how to use them. The fitness trainers are very expensive and I don't know how to start on my own. Watching youtube videos might help, but I won't be able to remember everything, how to exercise right and all the instruments. What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by picking 4-5 exercises, remember them, learn the form.

Start by performing these exercises with lighter weights to begin with so you can get used to controlling the weights.

Once you are used to these 4-5 exercises, start adding more and have an alternating routine until eventually you build up and you have a full "split" which is training all your body parts on different days.

As a beginner it would be very good if you looked up a full body beginners workout and do this 3 times a week with rest days in between to get started. Once you start with this you can progress from there.

I also recommend taking a friend (who doesn't have to be experienced either) just to get over the fear of going alone and having someone to keep you motivated with going.

Comment: All my friends go to gyms that are in the other part of the city and this fitness is right next to my building so I guess I will have to go alone. As for the exercises I will try to remember some from youtube and do them in the fitness and see how it goes. Otherwise I can save up for a trainer, for like 2-3 times and show me everything so I can go from there, but I will try alone first to see if it's gonna work out. Thank you!

Comment: @CritingZ Try watching Athlean-X, hes a trusted youtuber who shows you the right ways to do things

Comment: thank you very much! I will look into his videos right after work! +